# Unsatisfiable Assumptions in Z3?

Tags: z3, smt

According to the SMTLib doc [here](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.5-r2015-06-28.pdf), we can check sat using `check-sat-assuming` and then one can determine the unsatisfiable assumptions using `get-unsat-assumptions`.

Reflecting that on Z3 in JavaAPI, I can see `checkAssuming` API doing the same thing as the`check-sat-assuming` but I can't seem to find anything that is doing something similar to `get-unsat-assumptions`, all I can find is `getUnsatCore` api.

So my question is, is there anyway that I can get unsat assumptions in Z3 using JavaAPI?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an oversight in the Java API. You might want to file a ticket (or better yet a pull-request) at their github site: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues